# Flutter admob ads not showing

Tags: flutter, admob, ads

Using flutter I added admob ads to my app and can successfully serve test ads. However when I switch the app id and ad id to the production/real ads, I get 'Request Error: No ad to show'. I've seen several answers to this most common being to just wait a few days. I've been waiting over a week and still nothing. I don't get it, what am I doing wrong? Any thoughts would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, have you published the app? Have you linked it in AdMob? They have reviewed the app? Real ads appears after a process, not just publishing or trying

Comment: I have not published to the app store yet. Is that a requirement for real ads to show?

Comment: Of course, they need to be sure that your users come from a safe source, such as a store. Otherwise they might think that you and your friends use the app and see ads that make you money, this would be invalid traffic, and to avoid this, you need to have a source of users, a store.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Appreciate it!